# Shell logging for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

I am new to mongodb and trying to figure out a lot.

Can we configure shell logging for mongodb? What I mean is the capability to get logs from the Shell to track queries for auditing purposes for version 4?

If so - what commands do we have to run please?

Thank you for your help

Comment: There are two versions of MongoDB shell: the newer `mongosh` and the `mongo` shell. The `mongosh` has its logs at [Retrieve Shell Logs](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/logs/).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of MongoDB shell: the newer [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/) and the older/legacy [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/) shell.

`mongo` maintains a history of commands in the [.dbshell](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-dbshell-file) file. For example, in the Windows 7 environment this can be found at the folder: `C:\Users\<user_name>`

MongoDB Shell `mongosh` stores logs for each session and can be retrieved as explained at: [Retrieve Shell Logs](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/logs/). For example, in Windows environment this can be found at the folder: `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\`. The log files are of the format `<LogID>_log`.

Comment: In Unix and Linux environments `.dbshell` can be found in the user's home directory.