# Mongo dbshell command history

Tags: mongodb, docker, debian, mongodb-shell

I am trying to find the location of .dbshell storing, but I can't manage to find.

May I know normally where does it storing?

Environment:
Docker mongo
The server is installing in GCP, I am using debian server and run with ssh to manage the server.

Comment: See this SO post for some info: [Shell Logging for MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381346/shell-logging-for-mongodb)

Comment: hi @prasad_ , i have tried to find from the user folder, but no luck to find it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.